# How to match and group array elements with the max value in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need help to get the array element having maximum value of a field(level) from a document. Then count the total occurences grouped by array element field "bssid".

Consider the following data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "18:59:36:0c:94:a3",
    "timestamp" : "1460012567",
    "apdata" : [{
        "bssid" : "f4:b7:e2:56:e4:20",
        "ssid" : "Test Network2",
        "level" : -55
    }, {
        "bssid" : "b8:a3:86:67:03:56",
        "ssid" : "Test Network1",
        "level" : -76
    }]
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "d0:b3:3f:b9:42:38",
    "timestamp" : "1460013345",
    "apdata" : [{
        "bssid" : "f4:b7:e2:56:e4:20",
        "ssid" : "Test Network2",
        "level" : -65
    }, {
        "bssid" : "b8:a3:86:67:03:56",
        "ssid" : "Test Network1",
        "level" : -46
    }]
}
/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "d0:b3:3f:b9:42:41",
    "timestamp" : "1460013145",
    "apdata" : [{
        "bssid" : "f4:b7:e2:56:e4:20",
        "ssid" : "Test Network2",
        "level" : -65
    }, {
        "bssid" : "b8:a3:86:67:03:56",
        "ssid" : "Test Network1",
        "level" : -46
    }]
 }
```

The output required is

```
{
    "bssid" : "f4:b7:e2:56:e4:20",
    "ssid" : "Test Network2",
    "count" : 1
}, {
    "bssid" : "b8:a3:86:67:03:56",
    "ssid" : "Test Network1",
    "count" : 2
}
```

Which is the count of times each bssid had the maximum value within the array of each document over the whole collection.

Comment: _id is normally a unique identifier. How can you group by it?

Comment: @JohnGreenall If you followed the logic in the question it's asking to group on the `"appdata.bssid"` values, of which there are only "two" in every array. The point of the question is to *"Count the number of times a particular network has the level with the maximum value from all documents"*, as the best phrase in relevance to the question and data. And a problem that has some noteworthy approaches to solving as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MongoDB 3.2 available then you can do something like this:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "apdata": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$apdata",
          "as": "el",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [ 
              "$$el.level",
              { "$max": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$apdata",
                  "as": "data",
                  "in": "$$data.level"
                }
              }}
            ]
          }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$apdata.bssid",
    "ssid": { "$first": "$apdata.ssid" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

For at least MongoDB 2.6 you need to do this:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$apdata" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "apdata": { "$push": "$apdata" },
    "max": { "$max": "$apdata.level" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$apdata" },
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$eq": [ "$apdata.level", "$max" ] },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$apdata.bssid",
    "ssid": { "$first": "$apdata.ssid" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

And for MongoDB 2.4 or 2.2 like this:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$apdata" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "apdata": { "$push": "$apdata" },
    "max": { "$max": "$apdata.level" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$apdata" },
  { "$project": {
    "apdata": 1,
    "isMax": { "$eq": [ "$apdata.level", "$max" ] }
  }},
  { "$match": { "isMax": true } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$apdata.bssid",
    "ssid": { "$first": "$apdata.ssid" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

In all cases [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) is used to get the "maximum" value of of the array in each document "first", then you can use that to "filter" the array content prior to using it in a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). The approaches to this only vary with version

**MongoDB 3.2**: Allows the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) to work directly on an "array" of values. So the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) is used to just get the `"level"` values and find out what that "max" actually is.

Then the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) can be used to just return the array element which matches that "max" value, and finally [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) is used to return that "only" ( out of two possible and "zero" index ) element as a plain document.

The whole process can be done in [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) "only" if you basically repeat that whole statement for both the `_id` and in order to get the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) `"ssid"` value, but it's a bit easier to write in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) separately to demonstrate.

**MongoDB 2.6**: This lacks the fancier operators and most notably the ability of [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) to work "directly" on an array. The notable thing is the need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array first and then actually [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) just on the original document, solely in order to get that "max" value.

Then the process really needs you to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) again since you will be grouping on the element from the array later, and then use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to filter the content. This is a "logical" form of [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) where you can directly compare the `"level"` against the computed "max" from the earlier stage. So the element that is not the "max" is removed.

**MongoDB 2.4**: Is again basically the same logic, except instead of [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) you actually need the physical [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in order to put a field in the document to use in filtering with [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

---

All versions have the same final [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), where you supply the path to `"apdata.bssid"` for the grouping key and the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) result on that grouping boundary for the `"ssid"` and a simple [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count the occurrences of the grouping key in the results.

Everything returns just as follows:

```js
{ "_id" : "f4:b7:e2:56:e4:20", "ssid" : "Test Network2", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "b8:a3:86:67:03:56", "ssid" : "Test Network1", "count" : 2 }
```

---

Actually the most "efficient" form for MongoDB 3.2 would be as follows:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$apdata",
              "as": "el",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [ 
                  "$$el.level",
                  { "$max": {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": "$apdata",
                      "as": "data",
                      "in": "$$data.level"
                    }
                  }}
                ]
              }
            }            
          },
          "as": "apdata",
          "in": {
            "bssid": "$$apdata.bssid",
            "ssid": "$$apdata.ssid"
          }
        }},
        0
      ]
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

With a slightly different form due to the compound `_id`, but it is a single [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage only, without repetition of the whole process to find the array element data for the "max" value:

```js
  {
    "_id" : {
      "bssid" : "b8:a3:86:67:03:56",
      "ssid" : "Test Network1"
    },
    "count" : 2
  }
  {
    "_id" : {
      "bssid" : "f4:b7:e2:56:e4:20",
      "ssid" : "Test Network2"
    },
    "count" : 1
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Neil Lunn ..it works and Thanks for the detailed explaination.Helps  a lot for Mongodb beginner